# Jquery javascript link meaning

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

I have these these in my codes, and i don't really understand what is it for?( the codes on top)Is there a need to include these codes ?

**i need some help here..what is this mean??
and what can i replace this to call the js file??
this is something new for me..i hope somebody can help me...**
i try to call my js file from other folder..can i replace this with other??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

this script in very easy if you want to include onlclick js file

Answer (score 0):

It will include jQuery 1.71 if it's not already loaded. So, if you're sure that jQuery is not already loaded where you want to inlude the tag, you can replace it with

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's checking if you have jquery, and if not it loads it by writing the link after removing the escape characters.